# Assistance with Person Class

Tags: c++, class

I need help with figuring out how to code the given specifications since I'm really lost in how to use the three different source files and what needs to go in all of them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
  Person();
  string getName();
  int getAge();
  void setName(string newName);
  void setAge(int newAge);
  void display();

private:
  string name;
  int age;
};
```

This is all I have for Person.h so far.

Specification
1. Given Person.h
 1(a). Add a parametrized constructor that uses an initializer list for name and validates ago > 0
1(b). Create a Person.cpp that implements the functionality of Person.h

2. Create PersonTest.cpp that demonstrates the features of class Person

Comment: What's your question? All I see is: "This is my homework assignment, this is what I have so far, pls finish it for me". It's great you've got some code here (although it looks like that code came with the assignment, since it says: "Given Person.h"), but what is your question? Do you not know how what a parameterized constructor is, or a constructor initializer list, or how to implement a class?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by three different source files? If you mean Person.h, Person.cpp, and PersonTest.cpp, see below

a .h file (you should actually be using a .hpp file for c++ but it still technically works) is whats called a header file. This is where you would pretty much just name the class and all its attributes/methods, its the bare bones of the class that shows what the class is capable of doing without actually showing how its all done.

Person.cpp would be the file where you implement everything from the .h class. the top of your .h file should have something like this at the top:

```html
#include "Person.cpp"
```

This tells the .h file where to look for the implementation of the methods you previously declared. To implement a method, all you need to do is something like inside of the cpp file `

```html
void Person::setAge(int newAge) {

---implementation---

}
```

the "Person::" just shows that you are doing something inside of the Person class.

The third file is probably where your int main() is going to be, and make sure that at the top, it also has the #include for the header. Here is where you do what you want to test if your class is actually working, like checking that your outputs match what you expect, etc etc.

I hope this clarified a little of what you needed!

Answer (score -1):

Given you know what a constructor is, you should add to this file another constuctor :

```
Person(string name,int age);
```

in the file Person.cpp you develop all the functions defined in Person.h
The file PersonTest.cpp should have a main function that calls instances of Person and prove your class works